# Find the local max/mins of $f(x, y) = xy + 8/x + 8/y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I get no local maximums, a local minimum at $(2, 2)$, and no saddle points. Supposedly my answer for local minimum is incorrect and I keep making this same error. Please show me how to find the local minimum! I appear to be missing critical points because the only one I get from the partial derivatives' equaling zero is $(2, 2)$.

Note: point should be an element of the real numbers

Comment: What makes you think $(2,2)$ is not a local minimum?

Comment: Webassign says it's wrong... and since (2, 2) is a local min,  there must be more for it to be wrong, no?

Comment: (2, 2) IS a local min, but when I try to enter it in, Webassign says there are more local mins

Comment: Who or what is Webassign?

Comment: It's an online homework program. It's saying ALL of my answers are wrong so far I feel like giving up

Comment: Well there might be a good chance that it's the program messing up then. I trust that you did not get every single question on your homework wrong.

Comment: I think I figured it out. It was asking for the f(x, y) value at the min and not the point at which f(x, y) is minimized.

Comment: Be careful on computer-based instructional programs and exam problems (especially multiple-choice) to be clear on _exactly_ what the question is asking...

Comment: Does it ask for WHERE the local maximum is or WHAT the local maximum is?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The point (2,2) is a local minimum of the function, it takes the value 12 there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an animation of the surface of interest in three dimensions:

[image]

Here is a contour plot, looking down from the $z$-axis, clearly showing that there is a relative extremum around $(2,2)$:

[image]

It is not difficult to show mathematically that this extremum exists and is a relative minimum; and furthermore, that there are no other critical points.